# How to show Random ReactJS element skeleton

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-loading-skeleton to show skeleton on my react web app. Its working perfeclty without any issue.
I can use multiple skeleton with multiple design, but I want to randomize it. Like the facebook comments loading skeleton.

Is there any way to randomize it ?

Comment: What exactly you want to randomize? Count?

Comment: You can probably create multiple Skeleton components and then have a parent Skeleton return randomized result.

Comment: @AseemGautam the design. Sometimes i want to show three line sometimes one line with a photo skeleton

Comment: @Rikin Thanks a lot . Doing this. Is there any other way ?